# SFML C# Rotate View

Tags: c#, rotation, sfml

When looking through the documentation for SFML, I noticed the ability to rotate a View object, this seems to be lacking in C#/.net bindings, is it still possible? If not, are there work-arounds?

```
View V = new View(new FloatRect(0,0,640,640));
V.Rotate(45);
```

'SFML.Graphics.View' does not contain a definition for 'Rotate' and no extension method 'Rotate' accepting a first argument of type 'SFML.Graphics.View'

I'm using the .Net 1.6 version available here  http://www.sfml-dev.org/download.php

Comment: What are you using for the interop from C#?

Comment: The .Net version availible from http://www.sfml-dev.org/download.php

Comment: Well, if it isn't reflected, no pun intended, in the manager wrapper I'd let the SFML developers know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SFML 1.6 does not support this, Use SFML 2.0 Release Candidate.